# memory leak for java off heap when using kafka streaming

Tags: memory-leaks, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams, rocksdb

i using kafka streaming to join streams,but the off heap memory is out of control.

i use jemalloc to find the cause. 
first, the rocksdb use offheap memory in high percentage

```
1806344172  67.4%  67.4% 1806344172  67.4% rocksdb::BlockFetcher::ReadBlockContents
588400270  22.0%  89.4% 588400270  22.0% os::malloc@921040
132120590   4.9%  94.3% 132120590   4.9% rocksdb::Arena::AllocateNewBlock
50331648   1.9%  96.2% 50331648   1.9% init
17587683   0.7%  96.8% 17981107   0.7% rocksdb::VersionSet::ProcessManifestWrites
15688131   0.6%  97.4% 15688131   0.6% rocksdb::WritableFileWriter::WritableFileWriter
12943699   0.5%  97.9% 12943699   0.5% rocksdb::port::cacheline_aligned_alloc
11800800   0.4%  98.4% 12588000   0.5% rocksdb::LRUCacheShard::Insert
 8784504   0.3%  98.7% 1811954485  67.6% rocksdb::BlockBasedTable::PartitionedIndexIteratorState::NewSecondaryIterator
 7606272   0.3%  99.0%  7606272   0.3% rocksdb::LRUHandleTable::Resize
```

As time goes by， it was changed

```
Total: 4502654593 B
3379447055  75.1%  75.1% 3379447055  75.1% os::malloc@921040
620666890  13.8%  88.8% 620666890  13.8% rocksdb::BlockFetcher::ReadBlockContents
142606352   3.2%  92.0% 142606352   3.2% rocksdb::Arena::AllocateNewBlock
129603986   2.9%  94.9% 129603986   2.9% rocksdb::port::cacheline_aligned_alloc
67797317   1.5%  96.4% 67797317   1.5% rocksdb::LRUHandleTable::Resize
50331648   1.1%  97.5% 50331648   1.1% init
32501412   0.7%  98.2% 230760042   5.1% Java_org_rocksdb_Options_newOptions__
18600150   0.4%  98.6% 19255895   0.4% rocksdb::VersionSet::ProcessManifestWrites
16393216   0.4%  99.0% 16393216   0.4% rocksdb::WritableFileWriter::WritableFileWriter
 5629242   0.1%  99.1%  5629242   0.1% updatewindow
```

os::malloc@921040 comsume most of the memory, and always growthing

so anyone can give some help ?

Comment: os::malloc@921040  comsume about 4G now, and progress memory is 10G.

Comment: Not clear why you think this is a leak. How much data is actually in the topics being consumed?

Comment: The retention time of the stores used in a KStream-KStream join is 1 day by default -- hence, it will require a lot of memory for high input rated. In upcoming 2.4,0 release, it will be possible to set (and hence reduce) the retention time.

Comment: any updates on this @dongming?